# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[]

Tags: flutter, android-multidex

I have a Flutter app, and I encounter  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[]`  error when debugging it over Wi-Fi on a physical device.

android/app/build.gradle

```
        multiDexEnabled true
```

and

```
        multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-main-dex-list.txt')
        multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
```

and

```
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:1.0.1'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
    </application>

    <application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

multidex-main-dex-list.txt

```
    com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider.class
```

Any suggestions?? Thanks for trying help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this.
If your minSdkVersion is over 21 you dont need to implement multidex. So i have changed my minSdkVersion to 23 and removed all multidex lines than it fixed my problem.